# How to add a animation while unzipping files with php?

Tags: php, file, jquery-animate, unzip

I have to unzip large .zip files on my server. To prevent that someone is running the unzip code multiple times, I want to add a animation while unzipping.

Can you tell me how and where in the code I have to add the animation?
(unzip code is from stackoverflow)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/myzips/extract_path/');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'woot!';
} else {
  echo 'doh!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your script with Ajax and show some kind of animation while your php script is being executed.

Something like:

```
$("#animation").show()
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/your_script.php"
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(response){
        $("#animation").hide();
    }
});
```